# Krull's intersection theorem for commutative local not necessarily noetherian rings

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, local-rings

Is there a characterisation of those commutative local not necessarily noetherian rings that satisfy Krull's intersection theorem ? How can the intersection theorem be phrased in terms the module category of the ring or its completion ?

Comment: Wouldn't it just mean that $R\to \hat{R}$ is injective? 

Comment: Or the given ring $R$ is Hausdorff in the $M$-adic topology (where $M$ is its maximal ideal).

Comment: Someone should retag this, but I don't want to bump it to the top and it's not clear to me which tags are appropriate.